# "using" statment inside method can cause troubles of data corruption or Access violation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, using-statement

I have a task, that set data into a FIFO, then another thread read this data inside the FIFO one by one and send it via network later. The data converted to byte array when call `FIFO.Add`, as following:

```
public byte[] ByteArraySerialize()
{
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m))
        {
            writer.Write((int)this.Opcode);
            writer.Write(this.Data);
        }
        return m.ToArray();
    }
}
```

My question: Is it possible that the data will be corrupted or disposed before the sender thread reads it from FIFO? My question is to understand `using` inside method:
**Is this the way of using the `using` inside a method may cause GC to remove the `MemoryStream`, before the thread reads the data lets say after few second or minutes after this data entered the FIFO?**

Comment: @Delnan: He's not returning the MemoryStream, he's returning an array *copied from* the MemoryStream. So his code is fine.

Comment: He is also returning a copy of the data owned by a *disposed* instance. Although this works in the current implementation of `MemoryStream`, as long as he has taken the trouble to ask if there's problems here, that's hardly the right way of doing things. I'd say his code is *not* fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to read this question but let's start with the obvious way, the way it was written:

> Is this way of using the "using" inside a method may cause GC to remove the Memory Stream, before the thread read the data lets say after few second or minutest after this data enter the FIFO?

No. This will not be a problem. If you are able to read the data as part of the call to `.ToArray()`, then you already have a copy of the data. If GC later on collects the stream, the array will live on. **To be clear**, in relation to GC, if you can read a good copy of the internals of the stream at the point where you call `.ToArray()`, then that array will be OK afterwards. As per the documentation, you're getting a copy of the internal data, not a reference to it, and even so, if you have a reference to some internal data structure, GC will not be able to collect it.

**However**, another interpretation could be this: Is there something wrong with this code?

And well, yes, and no.

The current implementation of `BinaryWriter` will dispose of the underlying stream when the writer instance is disposed of. This means that the `MemoryStream` will be disposed of.

Let me copy your code and add some comments:

```
public byte[] ByteArraySerialize()
{
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m))
        {
            writer.Write((int)this.Opcode);
            writer.Write(this.Data);
        }

        // m is really disposed here
        return m.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Does this make a difference? Well, no. In the current implementation, disposing of the memory stream will not in any way trash it. But there is nothing guaranteed about the current implementation or its future, this is undocumented behavior. If you want this code to be stable and trustworthy for future versions or hotfixes to .NET, I would not write it like this.

As such, I would not use this way of doing it. I would rewrite the code as follows:

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m))
{
    writer.Write((int)this.Opcode);
    writer.Write(this.Data);

    writer.Flush();
    return m.ToArray();
}
```

This will ask the writer to flush all the data, and then you make a copy of the internal array of the memory stream, before that instance is disposed.

Either that, or use the overloaded constructor and ask the writer to leave the stream open:

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m, Encoding.UTF8, true))
    {
        writer.Write((int)this.Opcode);
        writer.Write(this.Data);
    }

    // m is no longer disposed here
    return m.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Just a comment that is almost off-topic: The encoding in the original question and in your first example is implicitly like `new UTF8Encoding()`. The parameterless constructor does not use a byte-order mark. The encoding you get from the static property `Encoding.UTF8` is more like `new UTF8Encoding(true)` where `true` means do use a byte-order mark. This is somewhat confusing. However in some cases the so-called preamble is not used at all, and then it is irrelevant if it is empty or consists of a byte-order mark.

Comment: It is even more confusing. The encoding used if nothing is specified equals `new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true)` while the static property `Encoding.UTF8` equals `new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: true, throwOnInvalidBytes: false)`.

Answer (score 5):

The call to `ToArray();` effectively makes a copy of the data you want.
So everything and anything happening to the MemStreams is irrelevant.

More generally, as long as your code can 'see' a piece of data then the GC can't recycle that piece.
Don't overthink this.

Suppose you had used:

```
 return m.GetBuffer();
```

Now you are returning the internal buffer of the MemStream. `m` will be Disposed but simply because you returned it, the buffer will outlive its owner.

Comment: The asker should not confuse `using` statements with GC behavior. Unless the `Dispose` method suppresses a *finalizer* that the class has, there is no relation between `using` and GC.

Comment: I mentioned the GC just to make my question sharp, I meant that disposing the object and all its resources. As I know and wanted to be sure is the data will be removed or not, mean as I know C# basically move data as reference, so the question: is the data will be copied or I may have "access violation" due to Disposing the m?

Comment: I think I answered that: No it won't lead to an AV.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is "Not in this case".
The memory stream could of course be disposed, however before that you'll have your data in byte[] array, which will stay.

Try adding `writer.Flush();` just after your `writer.Write(this.Data);`.

Comment: What would the Flush() accomplish? (That the subsequent Close/Dispose won't?)

Comment: I've encountered cases in the .NET where Dispose doesn't Flush. AFAIR it was with XmlDictionaryWriter in .NET 4.0. And, the documentation for BinaryWriter.Dispose doesn't say it causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying device.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no problem. The stream will not be disposed too early.

You talk about the GC, but the idea with `using` statements and `IDisposable` is that any resource will freed immediately when the object goes out of scope. We won't have to wait for the GC. In other words this has no relation to the GC.

Comment: The Stream will be disposed before this method returns. It just doesn't matter.

Comment: "too early"?, what mean too early, I need to be sure the data will not dispose as long as it is in the FIFO and AFTER send it.

Comment: @Joseph Well, the stream `m` will not be disposed *because of the outer-most `using` statement* before the array of bytes is created and written to, and all you need is that array. However, Lasse V. Karlsen has pointed out in his answer (which was after mine) that the `BinaryWriter` `writer` will, by default, dispose its underlying stream when `writer` is disposed, and that happens after the *inner-most* `using` statement finishes, and that is before the byte array is created. But refer to Karlsen's answer.